# How to reverse five element String array

Tags: java

Why is my loop not working?

Sample output:

> Jack
>   Jill
>   Bob
>   Martha

Sample output from for loop reverse:

> Martha
>   Bob
>    Jill
>   Jack

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{      
    Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter a String");
    String []x;
    x= new String[5];
    for(int i=0; i<args.length; i++)
    { 
       x[i]= kb.next();
    }   

    for(int i=5; i<=0; i--)
    { 
        System.out.println(x[i]);
    }             
}
}
```

Comment: You have an extra `}` at the end of your code. Probably a typo.

Comment: The question is marked as duplicate while the OP had actually problem with writing the `for` loop conditions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your for loop condition `i<= 0` will be `false` as `i = 5` and  Arrays are zero based indexed in java.

```
 for(int i=5; i >= 0; i--) // the condition i <=0 will not met if used
    { 
        System.out.println(x[i]); // it will give ArrayIndexOfBound Exception
    }
```

you should start from `i = 4` to `0`; Safest way is to write:

```
 for(int i= x.length -1; i >= 0; i--)
  { 
            System.out.println(x[i]); 
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

A `for` loop runs as long as the condition is true. `5<=0` is not true, so you never enter the loop.

Answer (score 1):

Use Collections.reverse

```
String[] s = new String[] {"one","two","three","four", "five"};
System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(s));
Collections.reverse(Arrays.asList(s));
System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(s));
```

this prints:

```
 [one, two, three, four, five]
 [five, four, three, two, one]
```